# How can I migrate my application from IOS 13 to IOS 14?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11, xcode12

I run my application with xcode11 and can publish it. However, I saw the following announcement published by apple;

"Starting April 2021, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be
built with Xcode 12 and the iOS 14 SDK."

what exactly should I do?
If I download xcode 12 and run my application, will the sdks update automatically? What should I do to install iOS 14 sdk?

Or do I need to "pod update" for my existing pods?
Under "build settings" of my project "IOS Deployment Target" 10 should I change this?
Should we detect "IOS Deployment Target" as supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, all you need is:

- test your application with device (simulator doesn't always works as has to) iOS 14+ to be sure all works fine;
- be sure that your application works with dark theme (all content is readable);
- archive your application using XCode 12+.

Regeneration of Pods, as I know, is not necessary. But you can catch some bugs, so it can be useful for further development.

P.S. one of bugs which I catched after Pods update: build failed when I tried to test application with Release build configuration. To fix it I changed `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` build setting of my `Pods.xcodeproj`-file to 'Yes' for all of my build configurations (Debug, Release, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

What exactly should I do?

> You only need to download the new xcode , run your app and archive it with that version of xcode

If I download xcode 12 and run my application, will the sdks update automatically?

> sdk 14 is shipped with the version no thing to do

Do I need to "pod update" for my existing pods?

> No you don't have to